# Counting and Running Totals in Python 3

Tags: python

Here's my current code:

```
def even(x):

   if x % 2 == 0: 
       even = True
   else:
       even = False   

   if even is True:
       print("Even")

   if even is False:
       print("Odd")

N=[1,3,2,4]

for x in N: 
   even(x)
```

As it is the function takes each input and prints whether it's Even or Odd, very basic.

I gave myself the objective of writing a function/script that will take a list of numbers and spit out something like: "There are 15 even numbers and 8 odd numbers." However, I'm having trouble understanding how to count up a running total of how many times my variable "even" is True or False. Furthermore I don't understand how to then use that variable outside the function. So far my best attempts result in an output like:

> There were 1 Odd numbers
>
> There were 1 Odd numbers
>
> There were 1 Even numbers
>
> There were 1 Even numbers

etc... for whatever is in list N.

Whereas what I want is:

> There were 2 Odd numbers
>
> There were 2 Even numbers

Can anyone help me learn how to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sum()` and `map()`:

```
def even(x):
    return (x % 2 == 0)   

N = [1,3,2,4,6,8]

n_even = sum(map(even, N))
print(n_even)
# 4
```

Now `even` returns `True` (1) if the number is even and `False` (0) otherwise. Now simply sum it up and you have the times an even number occurred.
Additionally, you might want to define `n_odd` as

```
n_odd = len(N) - n_even
```

Comment: So "return" is like saying: "If this condition is true return me 1"? Or does the returned value depend on other things?

Comment: @JordanS.: First, it evaluates the condition in parentheses and then returns True or False.

Comment: So I extend from that the function sum treats True as 1? Sorry if these are obtuse questions I've literally been using python for less than a week.

Comment: @JordanS.: That is correct, yes. From https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html: *Operations and built-in functions that have a Boolean result always return 0 or False for false and 1 or True for true, unless otherwise stated.*

Comment: Thank you! The solution to this is so simple! I have a lot to learn that's for sure.

Comment: @JordanS.: Grab a copy of [**Learn Python the hard way**](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/). Additionally, the "currency" on Stackoverflow is up/downvoting and accepting answers (green arrows/tick on the left). Best of luck!

Comment: That books seems like it'll be very helpful! Thanks for all your input :D

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(x % 2 == 0 for x in lst)
print "There are %d even numbers and %d odd numbers" % (c[True], c[False])
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining how Counter tells the difference between a True and False value?

Comment: The counter here is applied to a comprehension of the list - if a item is even (i.e., for the item `x` the expression `x % 2 == 0` returns `True`), it's counted as a `True`, and if not, it's counted as a `False`.

Comment: Ah ok! I get it now. Thanks for answering, I appreciate it.